# Duplicating R dataframe vector values using another vector as a guide

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have the following R dataframe: `df = data.frame(value=c(5,4,3,2,1), a=c(2,0,1,6,9), b=c(7,0,0,3,4))`. I would like to duplicate the values of `a` and `b` by the number of times of the corresponding position values in `value`. For example, Expanding `b` would look like `b_ex = c(7,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,4)`. No values of three or four would be in `b_ex` because values of zero are in `b[2]` and `b[3]`. The expanded vectors would be assigned names and be stand-alone.

Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks! I forgot to use ```data.frame```. Fixed now. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for :

```
result <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) rep(x[x != 0], df$value[x != 0]))
#$a
#[1] 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 6 6 9

#$b
#[1] 7 7 7 7 7 3 3 4
```

To have them as separate vectors in global environment use `list2env` :

```
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: `lapply` would probably be safer, as it will always return a `list` instead of sometimes a `matrix` if the 2 resulting vectors happen to be the same length.

Comment: Also, while I'm nitpicking, I think you want `x != 0` since this will fail to `rep`eat negative values otherwise.

Comment: How do you repeat negative times? If there are negative values shouldn't they be dropped?

Comment: I mean negative values on the other side, like `-2` repeated 5 times, instead of `2` repeated 5 times. This will drop those I believe.

Comment: Ohh..I get it now. yes, you are right. Updated the answer.